# How to show an HTML5 validation error when a number is outside the range?

Tags: forms, numbers, range, survey, validationerror

I'm doing FreeCodeCamp's survey project but keep failing 9. If I enter numbers outside the range of the number input, I will see an HTML5 validation error.'

I don't understand because I though all I would have to do is add a min="10" max="100" thing. Here's what I have so far:

```
<label for="number" id="number-label" min="10" max="100"> Age </label>
    <input type="number" id="number" placeholder="Enter Your Age" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

min, max are attributes applied to numeric input elements. reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input
So you need the following changes to your code.

```
<label for="number" id="number-label" > Age </label>
    <input type="number" min="10" max="100" id="number" placeholder="Enter Your Age" required>
```